# Should the mirror id be unique in maven

Tags: maven

What will happen if i have two mirrors with same id in the settings.xml file?

Which one will be taken into account?

Comment: Is it really so hard to try it and see how it behaves? It's 1-minute experiment.

Comment: Replied, but you really should try bay yourself. Community is helping you, not serving you. (-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't do anything more than 1 repo.
You can even use it to have different mirrors with the same credentials.

But consider that you could did it by yourself ... This is a trivial question which take 1 minutes + build time to test by yourself.

Nevertheless :

```xml
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>mirror.repo.myorg.fr</id>
        <mirrorOf>!tiers-providers-public-snapshots,*</mirrorOf>
        <name>Repository Artifactory for snapshots.</name>
        <url>http://mirror.repo.myorg.fr/artifactory/repo-snapsthot</url>
    </mirror>
    <mirror>
        <id>mirror.repo.myorg.fr</id>
        <mirrorOf>!tiers-providers-public,*</mirrorOf>
        <name>Repository Artifactory for realeases</name>
        <url>http://mirror.repo.myorg.fr/artifactory/repo</url>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
```

This is the same machine, but two mirrors for differents purposes. I'm not sure this case would happen, but it is not so far of my own configuration.

I tried it, and it's obviously working.